# React Three Fiber HTML calculate width

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using React Three Fiber Drei HTML to display some textfields etc in a 3D scene.

I need to place some UI around the textfield and can't work out how to calculate the dimensions in Three coordinates.

i.e. if the div is 400px wide.

I'm getting close with `400/ viewport.factor / distanceFactor`

But it's not quite right.

How do I translate pixel width to Three factor?

Comment: Did you suceed ? Can I see your code ?

Comment: Nah I gave up. I removed the code so sorry no.